# SetInterval within jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am looking to iterate over a group of divs and perform some random actions at random times.  I am attempting to use the following function but `console.log` returns the same object and integer on every iteration.  What would be the proper way to perform the following?

```
    $('.cloud').each(function() {
    $cloud = $(this);
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
    setInterval(function() {
        setTimeout("console.log($cloud + ranNum)", ranNum)
    })
})
```

Comment: Why the setInterval? You didn't even specify a timeout!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use local (closure) variables by using `var`

Because you're providing functionality as a string, you have to use global variables. Your code should be written with local variables defined within the event anonymous function closure like this:

```
$('.cloud').each(function() {
    var $cloud = $(this);
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
    setInterval(function() {
        // $cloud won't have any particular meaning though
        console.log($cloud + ranNum);
    }, ranNum);
});
```

### Unusual combination of `setInterval` and `setTimeout`

Also I don't see a reason why you're using interval and timeout? Use one. Probably interval since you want something to repeatedly execute.

Comment: This did the trick. I was initial declaring them as global but failed to mention in question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please.. **never use a string as the first setInterval/setTimeout argument**

```
$('.cloud').each(function () {
    var $cloud = $(this);
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($cloud, ranNum);
    }, ranNum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your function so I'm going to rewrite and explain after:

```
$('.cloud').each(function(i,d) {
    var cloud = $(this);
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(cloud + ranNum)
    }, randNum );
});
```

I don't understand why you are trying to output `cloud` variable because this will just display HTMLElement or similar. Also, you are trying to put a timer inside a interval, both are the same, but the interval will keep looping, the timer will output once.

If you are trying to output which number cloud you are referencing. Use `i` instead of `cloud`.

Try define your variables a little cleaner, this is not PHP, refrain from using $ and don't forget var for initial definitions and ; to end statements!

Hope this helped.

Comment: It's somewhat common to prefix jQuery objects with `$` - it's perfectly valid. However, I'd only do that for `var $this = $(this);` and do not prefix other jQuery objects with `$`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Perfectly valid for `$this` yes, everything else is rather distracting because you start seeing jquery selectors everywhere.

Comment: I think there are arguments to be made for using $. Even though it's essentially hungarian, jQuery introduces an object that is representational of one or more DOM elements, and many functions can accept either DOM elements or jQuery objects. It's very easy to mix up whether you're working with a DOM element or a jQuery object, since they are sometimes (but not always) interchangeable, and you are often converting back and forth between them. This convention can help you avoid errors due to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here.  I will add that because you did not declare ranNum it ends up being a global variable and every iteration of the loop will overwrite the previous value instead of creating a new variable.  Thus the number you see in the log output will always be whatever random value was produced during the last iteration of the loop.

So, always declare your variables!